Eulerian identity $A(n+1,k) = (n+k-2) A(n,k-1)+k A(n,k)$
In notes I have, we are given the following (changing parenthesization to try to be clearer):
\begin{align*}
A_{n+1}(x) &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n+1} A(n+1,k)x^k\\
&= x\left(\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} A(n,k) x^{k-1}\right) - x^2\left(\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}(k-1)A(n,k-1) x^{k-2}\right)+(n+1)\left(\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}A(n,k-1)x^{k-1}\right) \end{align*}
I am not sure how we get the third equality. I suspect we are using the identity $A(n+1,k) = (n+2-k)A(n,k-1) + k A(n,k)$, but I don't see what happens to $n+1$ in the index of $k$ in the sums, and also why we start from $k = 0$ in the first sum after the third equality, but from $k = 1$ in the other two.
I'd be happy for any clarification.
Edit: Ok, I think there are typos in the notes. The author of the notes defines $\displaystyle A_{n}(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} A(n,k)x^k$ but according to wikipedia, it should be $\displaystyle A_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} A(n,k)x^k$.
Edit 2: I suspect the index $n+1$ vanishes because, by definition, we have $A(n,n+1) = \{\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n \;|\; \mathrm{des}(\pi) = n\}$, but a permutation in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ can not have more than $n-1$ descents.
Edit 3: My comment in edit 2 only applies when we have $A(n,k)$, and not when we have $A(n,k-1)$ since then we can at most have $A(n,n) = \{\pi \in \mathfrak{S}_n \;|\; \mathrm{des}(\pi) = n-1\}$, which is well-defined.

The full derivation of what I want to show, is the following: $x(1-x)\frac{d}{dx}A_n(x)+(n+1)xA_n(x) = A_{n+1}(x)$. I tried this:
\begin{align*}
x(1-x) \frac{d}{dx}A_n(x)+(n+1)xA_n(x) &= x(1-x) \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}k A(n,k)x^{k-1}+(n+1)x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} A(n,k)x^k\\
&= x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}kA(n,k)x^{k-1}-x^2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}kA(n,k)x^{k-1}+(n+1)x\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}A(n,k)x^k\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}k \cdot A(n,k)x^k- x^2\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}kA(n,k)x^{k-1}+(n+1)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}A(n,k)x^{k+1}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} k \cdot A(n,k)x^k +\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}(n+1-k)A(n,k)x^{k+1}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}k \cdot A(n,k)x^k+\sum\limits_{k' = 1}^{n+1}(n+1-(k'-1))A(n,k'-1)x^{k'}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k' = 1}^{n+1}\left(k' \cdot A(n,k')+(n+2-k')A(n,k'-1)\right)x^{k'}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k' = 1}^{n+1} A(n+1,k')x^{k'}\\
&= A_{n+1}(x).
\end{align*}
I might be missing a term $1$ here. Perhaps it works out if we instead define $A_n(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} A(n,k)x^k$ (which is how the notes defines $A_n(x)$); I'll edit the post accordingly (changing each $k = 0$ to $k = 1$):
\begin{align*}
x(1-x) \frac{d}{dx}A_n(x)+(n+1)xA_n(x) &= x(1-x) \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}k A(n,k)x^{k-1}+(n+1)x\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} A(n,k)x^k\\
&= x\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}kA(n,k)x^{k-1}-x^2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}kA(n,k)x^{k-1}+(n+1)x\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}A(n,k)x^k\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}k \cdot A(n,k)x^k- x^2\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}kA(n,k)x^{k-1}+(n+1)\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}A(n,k)x^{k+1}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n} k \cdot A(n,k)x^k +\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}(n+1-k)A(n,k)x^{k+1}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}k \cdot A(n,k)x^k+\sum\limits_{k' = 1}^{n+1}(n+1-(k'-1))A(n,k'-1)x^{k'}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k' = 1}^{n+1}\left(k' \cdot A(n,k')+(n+2-k')A(n,k'-1)\right)x^{k'}\\
&= \sum\limits_{k' = 1}^{n+1} A(n+1,k')x^{k'}\\
&= A_{n+1}(x).
\end{align*}
